# get the orientation of the device with unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

Im making my first 2d game with unity and im trying to do a main menu.

```
void OnGUI(){
    GUI.DrawTexture (new Rect (0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height), MyTexture);
    if (Screen.orientation == ScreenOrientation.Landscape) {
        GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width * .25f, Screen.height * .5f, Screen.width * .5f, 50f), "Start Game"); 
    } else {
        GUI.Button(new Rect(0, Screen.height * .4f, Screen.width, Screen.height * .1f), "Register"); 
    }
}
```

I want to write out start game button if the orientation of the device is in landscape and the register if it is in portrait. Now it writes out Register button even though i play my game in landscape mode. What is wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Screen.orientation` is used to tell the application how to handle device orientation events. It is probably actually set to `ScreenOrientation.AutoOrientation`. Assigning to this property dictates to the application what orientation to switch to, but reading from it does not necessarily inform you what orientation the device is currently in.

## Using the device orientation

You can use `Input.deviceOrientation` to get the device's current orientation. Note that the [`DeviceOrientation`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/DeviceOrientation.html) enum is fairly specific, so your conditionals might have to check for things like `DeviceOrientation.FaceUp`. But this property should give you what you're looking for. You'll just have to test the different orientations and see what makes sense for you.

Example:

```
if(Input.deviceOrientation == DeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft || 
     Input.deviceOrientation == DeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight) {
    Debug.log("we landscape now.");
} else if(Input.deviceOrientation == DeviceOrientation.Portrait) {
    Debug.log("we portrait now");
}
//etc
```

## Using the display resolution

You can get the display resolution using the `Screen` class. A simple check for landscape is:

```
if(Screen.width > Screen.height) {
    Debug.Log("this is probably landscape");
} else {
    Debug.Log("this is portrait most likely");
}
```

Comment: what do i compare input.deviceOrientation with to get if the orientation is in landscape or not?

Comment: See the hyperlink in my answer to `DeviceOrientation` (http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/DeviceOrientation.html). This contains values such as `DeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft`  representing a landscape device with the home button to the left. It has a few other more specific values though for instances such as a device that's parallel to the ground that you should probably also handle (i.e., many applications default to landscape in that situation).

I added an example to my answer.

Comment: i tried this Input.deviceOrientation == DeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft || Input.deviceOrientation == DeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight  but it still doesn't work. I start to think that maybe when you play the game and change the device resolution it acctually doesn't simulate the device in any orientation even though is says for example "WVGA Landscape 800x480"

Comment: First off, make sure you check `DeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft || DeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight`. That way you account for rotating the device in either direction. And yes, I don't think changing the display resolution is the same as changing the device orientation. I'll update my answer with a way to check using the display resolution.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But how to i simulate that the game is put in landscape mode or portrait mode in unity3d?

Comment: I can't really remember how to simulate it. I think if you change your build target to Android or iOS, you gain extra controls such as testing the device orientation.